# Weird symbol when reading file in C++

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I'm using `fstream` to access a file and extract its contents.  When I go to output its data I continue to get just one weird symbol. This is the process I'm using. I've used it before with success but now I seem to have an issue. Here is the code.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        char text;
        int waitForIt;
        fstream Txt1("In.txt", ios::in);


        cout << "\n\tcontents of In.txt:" << endl << endl;
        cout << "\t\t";
        Txt1.get(text);
        do {
            cout << text;
            Txt1.get(text);
        } while (!Txt1.eof());
        Txt1.close();
        cin >> waitForIt;
     };
```

This is what is being output:

[image: Symbol being output as char text]

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to write `while( text << fstream ) cout << text;`?

Comment: and what's the actual contents of your input file?

Comment: This code works fine for me. The problem might be with "In.txt"

Comment: It's a file in notepad.  It just contains "abc def ghi"

Comment: @IanBaughman Can you upload it? For some reason, microsoft's guys like to insert characters that you don't want (for example, BOM).

Comment: Perhaps your file is actually empty? In this case, you print a non-sense character ...

Comment: W/o seeing the actual file, we can only guess (as jpo38 has just done in his answer). Please provide a [Minimal Complete Verifyable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My expectation is the input file is in the wrong folder and there is no error checking all in the program. So even though it could not open the file it processes the uninitialized value in text.

Comment: Thanks guys, I actually deleted the content of the In.txt file thinking it was a out put file I was using later in the code.  Can't believe I didn't think to bother checking the file. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I bet your file could not be opened. The way you wrote your loop, you print the character you think you had read by using `get` function even if reading failed.

You should do:

```
fstream Txt1("In.txt", ios::in);
if ( Txt1.is_open() )
{
    cout << "\n\tcontents of In.txt:" << endl << endl;
    cout << "\t\t";
    while (!Txt1.eof())
    {
        Txt1.get(text);
        cout << text;
    }
    Txt1.close();
}
else
{
    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
}
```